# Continuing an already-answered question

Tags: discussion, answering-questions

Let's say I find [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/417921/why-do-modern-routers-not-require-clock-settings-anymore) which is similar to one I already have, but I don't understand the answer, even though the OP got it.

What's the best way to ask my question?

e.g. Should I post a reply to the other thread, make a new question but link to the other thread, comment, or anything else?

Comment: Voretaq's answer is correct in your case. In the more general case one would open a new question, reference the old, and explain why the new is different (and not answered by the old). But each situation is different...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on what you don't understand - the answer on that question is pretty comprehensive (and anything that's not covered could be better answered by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSU/DSU) (or [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_terminal_equipment), or [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_circuit-terminating_equipment)).

Generally the best thing to do is to ask a new question (with enough detail that it can stand on its own), make reference to the previous question, and explain why your question is different.

---

You can also pop into [Server Fault's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) for quick clarification (anything requiring in-depth explanation is probably better asked on the main site though, where more people will see it and benefit from it in the future).